# What does the %*s format specifier mean?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

In some code that I have to maintain, I have seen a format specifier `%*s` . Can anybody tell me what this is and why it is used?

An example of its usage is like:

```
fprintf(outFile, "\n%*s", indent, "");
```

Comment: It is important that the promoted type of `indent` is an `int`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[It's used to specify, in a dynamic way, what the width of the field is](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/):

> - The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional
>     integer value argument preceding the
>     argument that has to be formatted.

so "indent" specifies how much space to allocate for the string that follows it in the parameter list.

So,

```
printf("%*s", 5, "");
```

is the same as

```
printf("%5s", "");
```

It's a nice way to put some spaces in your file, avoiding a loop.

Comment: @EthanHeilman, the * means something COMPLETELY different in the scanf family of functions.

Comment: Note that if you have a negative number, the field will be left justified.  That is, `printf("[%*s]\n", -10, "hello")` will output "`[hello     ]`" rather than "`[     hello]`" which you would get if you use `+10` (or `10`).

Answer (score 11):

Don't use "%*s" on a buffer which is not NULL terminated (packed) thinking that it will print only "length" field.

Comment: Use "%.*s" to achieve this!

Comment: @AndyG I am having trouble understanding how '%.*s' helps with that. From the docs [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it looks like the only difference between the 2 format specifiers is that '%.*s' ignores negative precision values.

Comment: @powersource97, `%.*s` means you are reading the `precision` value from an argument, and precision is the maximum number of characters to be printed, and `%*s` you are reading the `width`  value from an argument, which is the minimum number os characters to be printed.

Answer (score 5):

The format specifier %4s outputs a String in a field width of 4—that is, printf displays the value with at least 4 character positions.

If the value to be output is `less` than 4 character positions wide, the value is `right justified` in the field by default.

If the value is `greater` than 4 character positions wide, the field width `expands` to accommodate the appropriate number of characters.

To left justify the value, use a negative integer to specify the field width.

References: [Java™ How To Program (Early Objects), Tenth Edition](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javatm-how-to/9780133813036/ch05lev2sec44.html)

Answer (score 3):

**When used in printf and fprintf:**

```
printf("%*s", 4, myValue); is equivalent to printf("%4s", myValue);
```

It displays the variable with minimum width, rest right-justified spaces. To left-justify the value, use a negative integer.

**When used in scanf and sscanf:**

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="Rudolph is 12 years old";
  char str [20];
  int i;

  sscanf (sentence,"%s %*s %d",str,&i);
  printf ("%s -> %d\n",str,i);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Rudolph -> 12
```

It is used to ignore a string.

Comment: in `sscanf()`, `"%s"` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) as it lacks a width limit.

Answer (score 1):

* Causes fprintf to pad the output until it is n characters wide, where n is an integer value stored in the a function argument just preceding that represented by the modified type.

```
printf("%*d", 5, 10) //will result in "10" being printed with a width of 5.
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

> The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

e.g: `printf("%*s", 4, myValue);` is equivelant to `printf("%4s", myValue);`.