# How does this printf trick works

Tags: c, printf

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599365/what-is-your-favorite-c-programming-trick?rq=1):

`printf("%d", printf("%*s%*s",a,"\r",b,"\r") );`

Will print the result of a+b.

How on earth does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the %\*s format specifier mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000556/what-does-the-s-format-specifier-mean)

Comment: No dup. Can be a hint for this question though

Comment: It's obfuscation and not really worth pondering about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the second(inner) printf does is to print as many chars as `a` and then as many chars as `b`. `printf` returns the number of chars printed, thus the sum of `a` and `b`.

Now let's get a bit deeper `printf("%*s", a, "\r")` will print a string with width specified via a parameter(in this case `a`) - that is what the asterisk does. By default the string is left padded with spaces. Thus you will get `a - 1` spaces followed by a carriage return char. Doing it twice: `printf("%*s%*s",a,"\r",b,"\r")` will first print a string with width fixed to the value of `a` and then a second string with width fixed to the value of `b`.

After that the outer `printf` will print the number corresponding to the number of chars printed by the inner `printf`, but we already know what that would be, don't we?

NOTE: as left padding can only add, will never remove chars, the code is in fact wrong for `a = 0` or `b = 0` (or negatives of course)

Answer (score 2):

Since `printf` returns the character count in output, and the `%*s` specifier actually reads two arguments (an integer and a character) and prints the character indented (so n-1 spaces are printed before it), essentially the inner `printf` printed `a`+`b` `\r`s, and the outer `printf` printed that number.

Comment: `%*s` takes a number and a string, not a character, and formats the string by padding on the left with spaces to at least the width given by the number.